# Why is "Thomism" pronounced with a long "o" unlike "Thomas"?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is 'Thomism' (and 'Thomistic') pronounced with a long 'o', while 'Thomas' is not?

I occasionally hear the word mispronounced, and my gentle correction is typically met with disbelief.

Comment: Probably because the name is pronounced with a long o in [ancient Greek](https://forvo.com/search/%CE%98%CF%89%CE%BC%E1%BE%B6%CF%82/grc/) and [Latin, including Church Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thomas#Pronunciation_3).

Comment: I always assumed that it was because Aquinas was a weighty Thom.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no particularly robust reason for the pronunciation of this word. It's just the established pronunciation.

My impression is that most words ending with *-ism* have more than one syllable preceding it. In these circumstances, the stress tends to go on the second syllable before it, and the vowel is pronounced short if it is a single vowel letter before a consonant letter other than "h". Examples: *metabolism, antagonism, neologism, exoticism.* There are also words with long vowels in this context, mainly more recent coinages like *tribalism* (from *tribal*), *vitalism* (from *vital*).

There are a smaller number of words where only one syllable precedes the *-ism*.

- Sometimes, this syllable is identical to an independent word (ignoring final silent *e*), and has the same vowel length as the independent word. Examples: *racism* (like *race*), *statism* (like *state*).
- Sometimes, this syllable is not identical to any independent word. Vowel length in this case seems pretty unpredictable, and variable between speakers. Examples:

  - *holism*: The OED says "Brit. /ˈhəʊlɪz(ə)m/, /ˈhɒlɪz(ə)m/,  U.S. /ˈhoʊlˌɪzəm/". The word comes from Greek ὅλος "whole", which has a short vowel. It seems plausible to me that the pronunciation has been influenced by the pronunciation of the English word "whole".
  - *tropism*: The OED says "Brit. /ˈtrəʊpɪz(ə)m/, U.S. /ˈtroʊˌpɪz(ə)m/". It's ultimately derived from Greek *-τροπος,* with a short vowel.
  - *sophism*: The OED says "Brit. /ˈsɒfɪz(ə)m/, U.S. /ˈsɑˌfɪzəm/, /ˈsoʊˌfɪzəm/". It's from Greek *σόϕισμα* (with a short vowel), mediated via Latin and/or French.
  - *monism*: The OED says "Brit. /ˈmɒnɪz(ə)m/, U.S. /ˈmɑˌnɪz(ə)m/, /ˈmoʊˌnɪz(ə)m/". It's from German *Monismus,* ultimately from ancient Greek *μόνος* "single" (with a short vowel).
  - *psephism*: The OED says "Brit.  /ˈ(p)siːfɪz(ə)m/, /ˈ(p)sɛfɪz(ə)m/,  U.S. /ˈ(p)siˌfɪz(ə)m/". From Greek *ψήϕισμα* via Latin *psēphisma* (with long vowels).

Even though "Thomism" is related to the name "Thomas," it isn't actually built on this name (it's not "Thomas-ism") so it seems to fall into the second category above rather than the first.

As 1006a said in a comment, people's knowledge of Greek vowel length seems to have influenced the pronunciations of these words, but I don't know if I would say that this influence is strong enough to be considered a rule. Still, it's probably the best explanation that exists for the standard pronunciation of *Thomism.*

(Another contributing factor may be the common tendency in English for a single vowel letter to be given its "long" pronunciation before a single intervocalic consonant letter. It has exceptions, but the examples of *holism* and *tropism* suggest that this tendency is somewhat active in words ending in *-ism*.)

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to illustrate with the examples *metabolism, antagonism, thermotropism*. The first two follow what I *thought* you were trying to say, but I have only heard *thermotropism* pronounced with the second-to-last syllable stressed, with the same vowel sound as "trope". [This site](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thermotropism) corroborates my experience.

Comment: @JohnY: Really? I guess that one's variable also then; I didn't realize. The OED and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thermotropism) only show stress on the "mot".